# NativeScript Does Not Recognize "android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS"

Tags: android, angular, android-permissions, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Hello I am new to mobile development and Angular 2. I am trying to request permission for reading contacts, however NativeScript is not recognizing "android".

For exmple I am not able to run the following code:

`permissions.requestPermission(android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET, "I need these permissions because I'm cool");`

```
Error: Cannot find name 'android'.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show the whole code

Comment: Thank you Marcin, I was able to resolve the issue by following Nathanael's instructions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the top of your TS file just add:

`declare var android: any;`

TypeScript does not know what "android" is; so you have to tell it what it is

The other way to fix this is to download the platform typings 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations and then install them.   Please note the Typings do typically slow down compilation as they add a lot of data that has to be parsed...

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the NativeScript-Permissions plugin you are using.  ;-)

Comment: Thank you sir! Thank you for answering my question and also thank you for authoring the NativeScript-Permissions plugin :)

Comment: Might as well try out the `--androidTypings` option during tns run/build to have typings built for your current compileSdk android version :D